# Print sql query responsible for generating reports in Admin > Reports > Sales > Orders

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, sales-order, sql, reports

I need to do exactly I asked in the question.

I have overrided the reports generation file `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Adminhtml/Block/Report/Sales/Sales/Grid.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Adminhtml/Block/Report/Sales/Sales/Grid.php`.

Now I want to print the query that is being generated but I am clueless when I see the `ResourceModel` is set dynamically like below:

```
public function getResourceCollectionName()
    {   
        return ($this->getFilterData()->getData('report_type') == 'updated_at_order')
            ? 'sales/report_order_updatedat_collection'
            : 'sales/report_order_collection';
    }
```

I modified this function like below but in vain:

```
public function getResourceCollectionName()
    {   
        $resCollName = ($this->getFilterData()->getData('report_type') == 'updated_at_order')
            ? 'sales/report_order_updatedat_collection'
            : 'sales/report_order_collection';
        echo Mage::getResourceModel($resCollName)->getSelect();die;
        return $resCollName;
    }
```

How to print query generated in this function so I don't have to override the `Abstract.php` file ?

Answer (score 2):

you can use below syntax to print SQL query.

```
echo $collection->getSelect();
```

Comment: But if you seen that file, there is no `$collection` object being used there, just the resource collection function name is declared and the columns are getting data without setting collection probably.

Comment: As per your requirement, collection is loaded in app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Report/Grid/Abstract.php file.

in _prepareCollection() function collection is loaded.

Comment: Any chance I could print query in this file and function without need to put `Abstract.php` in local directory ?

Comment: Any idea where this sql query is written? Can I check that sql query?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49597827/sql-query-path-for-grid-in-the-magento-architecture

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
echo $collection->getSelect()->__toString();
```

if you want to log then add below syntax:

```
$collection->printLogQuery(false, true);
```